# How to calculate category frequencies for all variables for each group separately with absolute and percentage values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

my dataset has such structure

```
structure(list(GR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Skin..visible.mucous.membranes..hair..nails.1 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.lymph.nodes.1 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), ENT.organs..respiratory.system.1 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.cardiovascular.system.1 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Gastrointestinal..including.assessment.of.spleen.and.liver.size..1 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Genitourinary.sphere.1 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Nervous.system.1 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Psychic.Sphere.1 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Skin..visible.mucous.membranes..hair..nails.2 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.lymph.nodes.2 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), ENT.organs..respiratory.system.2 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.cardiovascular.system.2 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Gastrointestinal..including.assessment.of.spleen.and.liver.size..2 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Genitourinary.sphere.2 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Nervous.system.2 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Psychic.Sphere.2 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Skin..visible.mucous.membranes..hair..nails.3 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.lymph.nodes.3 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), ENT.organs..respiratory.system.3 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), The.cardiovascular.system.3 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Gastrointestinal..including.assessment.of.spleen.and.liver.size..3 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Genitourinary.sphere.3 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Nervous.system.3 = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"
), Psychic.Sphere.3 = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

this is part of the results of the study on which i need to calculate the frequencies for the normal or not normal categories.

How to calculate frequencies for categories of `normal` and `not normal` for each of studied parameter for each group separately

```
Skin, visible mucous membranes, hair, nails
The lymph nodes
  ENT organs, respiratory system
The cardiovascular system
Gastrointestinal (including assessment of spleen and liver size)
Genitourinary sphere
Nervous system
Psychic Sphere
```

and each of them has a digital prefix, for example The lymph nodes 1 - means the first day of the study, The lymph nodes 2 - means the second day of the study. To make a reproducible example, I took only 3 days.
And each parameter has, of course, `GR` study groups.

so that the desired final table looks like with absolute and percentage values

I know how to use the `table` command, but it does not allow me get desired output result in exactly the format that I showed in the figure.(this output i self create manually using full data and here it as example desired format)
[image]

How can I calculate frequencies like this to get needed desired output?

Comment: Does not seem like you have "not normal" in your example data set.

Comment: You might want to use tbl_summary from package gtsummary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a code as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

> df
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   Var      GR result      days
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 skin      1 normal         1
 2 skin      1 normal         1
 3 skin      2 normal         1
 4 skin      2 normal         1
 5 skin      1 not_normal     1
 6 skin      2 not_normal     1
 7 skin      1 not_normal     1
 8 skin      1 normal         2
 9 skin      1 normal         2
10 skin      2 normal         2
11 skin      1 not_normal     2
12 skin      2 not_normal     2
13 skin      1 not_normal     3
14 skin      1 not_normal     3
15 skin      2 normal         3
16 skin      2 normal         3
17 skin      2 normal         3
18 skin      2 not_normal     3


df %>% group_by(Var, GR,days, result) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(p = round(100 * n / sum(n, na.rm = T),2), rep = paste0( n, " (", p,"%)")) %>% select(-n , - p)  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = days, names_prefix = "day_", values_from = rep) %>% arrange( Var, GR, result)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   Var, GR [2]
  Var      GR result     day_1      day_2      day_3   
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>   
1 skin      1 normal     2 (50%)    2 (66.67%) NA      
2 skin      1 not_normal 2 (50%)    1 (33.33%) 2 (100%)
3 skin      2 normal     2 (66.67%) 1 (50%)    3 (75%) 
4 skin      2 not_normal 1 (33.33%) 1 (50%)    1 (25%)
```